# Copying files in python using shutil

Tags: python, file, shutil

```
I have the following directory structure:

 -mailDir
     -folderA
         -sub1
         -sub2
         -inbox
            -1.txt
            -2.txt
            -89.txt
            -subInbox
            -subInbox2
     -folderB
         -sub1
         -sub2
         -inbox
            -1.txt
            -2.txt
            -200.txt
            -577.txt
```

The aim is to copy all the txt files under inbox folder into another folder.
For this I tried the below code

```
import os
from os import path
import shutil

rootDir = "mailDir"
destDir = "destFolder"

eachInboxFolderPath = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    for dirName in dirs:
        if(dirName=="inbox"):
            eachInboxFolderPath.append(root+"\\"+dirName)

for ii in eachInboxFolderPath:
    for i in os.listdir(ii):
        shutil.copy(path.join(ii,i),destDir)
```

If the inbox directory only has .txt files then the above code works fine. Since the inbox folder under folderA directory has other sub directory along with .txt files, the code returns permission denied error. What I understood is shutil.copy won't allow to copy the folders.

The aim is to copy only the txt files in every inbox folder to some other location. If the file names are same in different inbox folder I have to keep both file names. How we can improve the code in this case ? Please note other than .txt all others are folders only.

Comment: I'd suggest using `os.path.isfile` or `os.path.isdir` functions to check whether an item is a directory/folder. Then you can avoid trying to copy the folder. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html

Comment: This worked. If the file names are same, then it is overwriting while I have to keep both the files. How we can do that ?

Comment: You have to rename one (or both), because (obviously) two files with the same name cannot simultaneously exist in the same path. So, I would suggest using `shutil.copyfile` instead of `.copy`. You'll need to first check for existence of the file in the destination folder.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is to filter for any `i` that does not have the `.txt` extension by using the string [`endswith()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_endswith.asp) method.

```
import os
from os import path
import shutil

rootDir = "mailDir"
destDir = "destFolder"

eachInboxFolderPath = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    for dirName in dirs:
        if(dirName=="inbox"):
            eachInboxFolderPath.append(root+"\\"+dirName)

for ii in eachInboxFolderPath:
    for i in os.listdir(ii):
         if i.endswith('.txt'):
            shutil.copy(path.join(ii,i),destDir)
```

This should ignore any folders and non-txt files that are found with `os.listdir(ii)`. I believe that is what you are looking for.

Comment: In the real scenario there is no .txt extension appended to the file. I can see just like 1, 2 etc. I put .txt here to just make it more clear. Sorry if that misguides.

Comment: That should work, but probably more appropriate to use either of the `os.path.isfile` or `os.path.isdir` functions: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html

Answer (score 0):

Just remembered that I once wrote several files to solve this exact problem before. You can find the source code [here on my Github](https://github.com/JimBoonie/PythonHelpers/blob/master/horsetools/file_utils.py).

In short, there are two functions of interest here:

- `list_files(loc, return_dirs=False, return_files=True, recursive=False, valid_exts=None)`
- `copy_files(loc, dest, rename=False)`

For your case, you could copy and paste these functions into your project and modify `copy_files` like this:

```
def copy_files(loc, dest, rename=False):
    # get files with full path
    files = list_files(loc, return_dirs=False, return_files=True, recursive=True, valid_exts=('.txt',))

    # copy files in list to dest
    for i, this_file in enumerate(files):
        # change name if renaming
        if rename:
            # replace slashes with hyphens to preserve unique name
            out_file = sub(r'^./', '', this_file)
            out_file = sub(r'\\|/', '-', out_file)
            out_file = join(dest, out_file)
            copy(this_file, out_file)
            files[i] = out_file
        else:
            copy(this_file, dest)

    return files
```

Then just call it like so:

```
copy_files('mailDir', 'destFolder', rename=True)
```

The renaming scheme might not be exactly what you want, but it will at least not override your files. I believe this should solve all your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import os
from os import path
import shutil

destDir = '<absolute-path>'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    # Filter out only '.txt' files.
    files = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.txt')]
    # Filter out only 'inbox' directory.
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d == 'inbox']

for f in files:
    p = path.join(root, f)
    # print p
    shutil.copy(p, destDir)
```

Quick and simple.

sorry, I forgot the part where, you also need unique file names as well. The above solution only works for distinct file names in a single inbox folder.

For copying files from multiple inboxes and having a unique name in the destination folder, you can try this:

```
import os
from os import path
import shutil

sourceDir = os.getcwd()
fixedLength = len(sourceDir)

destDir = '<absolute-path>'

filteredFiles = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sourceDir):
    # Filter out only '.txt' files in all the inbox directories.
    if root.endswith('inbox'):
        # here I am joining the file name to the full path while filtering txt files
        files = [path.join(root, f) for f in files if f.endswith('.txt')]
        # add the filtered files to the main list
        filteredFiles.extend(files)

# making a tuple of file path and file name
filteredFiles = [(f, f[fixedLength+1:].replace('/', '-')) for f in filteredFiles]

for (f, n) in filteredFiles:
    print 'copying file...', f
    # copying from the path to the dest directory with specific name
    shutil.copy(f, path.join(destDir, n))

print 'copied', str(len(filteredFiles)), 'files to', destDir
```

If you need to copy all files instead of just txt files, then just change the condition `f.endswith('.txt')` to `os.path.isfile(f)` while filtering out the files.